# How to Stop RecyclerView from moving to Top when New Data is fetched?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> Hello Everyone, Thank your for your Time. I am loading data inside a recyclerView using Pagination, but everytime any new data is fetched, the recyclerView moves itself to TOP !

> This is my Activity class code :

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
   
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        volleyModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        volleyAdapter = new VolleyAdapter(getActivity(), volleyModelList);
        NewVolleyData(requestCount);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

   public void NewVolleyData(int requestCount) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL+ requestCount +"&_embed", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    VolleyModel volleyModel = new VolleyModel();

                  
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");
                    JSONObject embeddedObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_embedded");
                    JSONArray wpTermArray = embeddedObject.getJSONArray("wp:term");
                    JSONObject contentObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("content");
                    description = contentObject.getString("rendered");

                    JSONArray authorArray = embeddedObject.getJSONArray("author");                 
                    authorName = insideAuthorArray.getString("name");
                    volleyModelList.add(new VolleyModel(id, title, finalName, image, date, commentCount, description, authorName));
                    volleyAdapter = new VolleyAdapter(getActivity(), volleyModelList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(volleyAdapter);
                    volleyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

> How can I stop moving the RecyclerView to Top whenever any new data is fetched ?

Comment: set adapter once and only modify its elements... also there is no need for calling `notifyDataSetChanged` right after you set adapter

Comment: moreover your code doesn't make sens ... you are creating new adapter in every loop step

Comment: If i dont set notifyDataSetChanged , will the data be updated in the recyclerView  ?

Comment: @Selvin Please guide with some code sample, what should I modify ?

Comment: *will the data be updated in the recyclerView* yes ... as you are setting adapter

Answer (score 1):

Yes becasue ever time you fetch your data you are creating a new adapter that the reason your recycerView scrool on the top remove this from your volly class

```
volleyAdapter = new VolleyAdapter(getActivity(), volleyModelList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(volleyAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way not creating every time adapter

```
if(volleyAdapter==null){
   volleyAdapter = new VolleyAdapter(getActivity(), volleyModelList);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(volleyAdapter);
}else{
   volleyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```